# Flutter show blank app after set in background

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter app in ipa from store show blank page after set in background for awhile no design or text appear but if click show navigate to pages but with no design/text
Link for images
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1tEOnM2-To43H_qDA2hjnBMoiQzQz3IL-

Comment: If your code has a syntax error and you build and deploy it.. once the user install they will get a blank screen when they navigate to the page. Check for errors in the code no matter how small

Comment: it's not happening in normal cases it happens when app sent to the background for multiple hours then user go and relaunch it again

Comment: it's relate to this issue 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64558?notification_referrer_id=MDE4Ok5vdGlmaWNhdGlvblRocmVhZDEwOTYwNTg5Njc6MTc2NTY4NzY%3D#issuecomment-703648866